# IIS 7.5 - Can I Disable NT Authentication if a Certain String Appears in the URL?

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-authentication

Simple question with possibly not such a simple resolution (if at all)

Can I turn off NU authentication is a URL contains a certain string? For example, let NT authentication be enabled for all URLs apart from ones that contain "thumbs"

Thanks

Comment: You want to let the user decide on how they authenticate to your website based on a string in the URL? Does the word "Security" mean *anything* to you at all?

Comment: So is that a yes or a no :-) it's to call images which need to be public but are automatically created from the app

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment you're trying to solve a problem with a wrong solution. You can set authentication against a folder in IIS:

At the bottom press 'content view' -> browse to the folder needed (double click it to be 'in' the folder) -> at the bottom press 'feature view' -> Authentication -> Set as needed -> profit!

Hope this helps.

Comment: The folders are automatically generated

Comment: Well then either research how to manage settings like this from powershell or any other way programmaticaly and build that in or always have a root folder called 'public content' and set permissions on that. Just suggestions but trying to manage security of the hosting platform through the URL is really a bad idea.